# XsltListViewWebPart is not displaying proper view when added programmatically

Tags: 2010, xslt-list-view-web-part, view

I am adding an XsltListViewWebPart from code behind, my code is:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        SPSite site = new SPSite("http://bipc11:1234/sites/publishing1");
        SPWeb web = site.RootWeb;
        web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
        SPLimitedWebPartManager webParts = web.GetLimitedWebPartManager(web.Url + "/SiteAssets/webparts.aspx", System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts.PersonalizationScope.Shared);
        SPList list = web.Lists["Images"];
        XsltListViewWebPart webPart = new XsltListViewWebPart();
        webPart.ListId = list.ID;
        webPart.XslLink = web.Url + "/Style Library/Custom View/ViewCart.xsl";
        webParts.AddWebPart(webPart, "Right", 0);
        webParts.SaveChanges(webPart);
        web.Update();
        Console.WriteLine("Web Part Added Successfully");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Images is the library in which pictures are stored and the path `web.Url +"/Style Library/Custom View/ViewCart.xsl` specifies the copy of file `AssetPicker.xsl` which renders data in thumbnail view.

My problem is that webpart displays [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zZj0p.png) output instead of displaying [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bkOc.png).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you think right view is not included in the  `XsltListViewWebPart`, then you can get the instance of the correct view and add it to the webpart:

```
SPView view = list.Views["Thumbnails"];
webPart.ViewId= view.ID.ToString("B").ToUpper()
```

Comment: Thanks sir, but I want to make some changes in the view i.e. I want to put small icon before each image title. So, if I modify the view it will be applied to all libraries, that's why I copied the AssetPicker file.

Comment: Am I following right way? @Nadeem Yousuf

Comment: The view is associated to a single list/library. Modifying it wont have any impact on other libraries/lists in the site.

Comment: Ok, I tried your code but it throws error that `webPart.ViewId` is `int` and `view.ID` is of type `Guid`

Comment: Then I tried other way like : `webPart.ViewGuid=list.Views["Thumbnails"].ID.ToString();` but it shows error that "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" at the line of adding the web part from web part manager.

Comment: Try this webPart.ViewGuid = list.Views["Thumbnails"].ID.ToString("B").ToUpper(); http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.in/2012/08/programatically-add-xsltlist-view.html

Comment: Sir, I want to know one more thing that if I edit the web part from sharepoint designer will it affect to all libraries or only that web part view?

Comment: As mentioned earlier, a view is associated to only one list. It is a one to one relation ship. I have updated my earlier answer. Mark it as an answer.